# Capture everything on computer screen and audio. What technologies/apis are involved?

Tags: audio, video, webrtc

I use Skype (macOS native app) and Google Hangouts (web) a lot for work. I will speak with clients using these apps while my headphones are plugged in to prevent others in the office from hearing both sides of the conversations.

I would like to find a way to record the video and audio from these conversations. Can I record audio coming in from Skype if I create a web app? I don't think WebRTC can solve this question.

Apologies for the vagueness and open-endedness of this question but searching online only returns app specific answers.

I would like to record the audio and video with Javascript on my side of the conversation. Am open to a webapp, or a chrome/ff plugin, or something else I'm not familiar with.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've had nothing but great experiences with loom (and it's free!). https://www.useloom.com/

Comment: Loom does not record audio when I have headphones on, nor does it record system audio (like when iTunes is playing when I have headphones on). It does however record my audio, but I need to record incoming audio as well.

Comment: Ah, right, my mistake. I've only ever used it to capture conferences with speakers and an open mic. Consider looking into software tailored to live streamers? Should have all of the features you're looking for. Sorry I'm not more help!

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thank you